# edittext cross (X) button not disappearing when empty

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I have implemented a cross button inside an `edittext`. The `edittext` is actually a search bar. This cross button will clear all the text the user has entered.

I want the cross button to disappear when the search bar is empty and be visible when its not.
When I type something it becomes visible but when i clear out everything, its still visible.
What can be the prob?

Here's my code:
**XML**

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchbar"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="#bfc2d1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/deletebackground_nooverlay"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:hint="Search the elements"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/backdrawbtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/backdrawbtn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clear_button"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/searchbar"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/searchbar" />
```

**Java**

```
 searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 //I am using textwatcher as this editttext (searchBar) has a search function as will
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            String searchedquery = cs.toString().replaceAll(" ","");
            CurlActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(searchedquery);
            if(!searchBar.getText().equals(""))
            {
                clearbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(searchBar.getText().equals(""))
            {
            clearbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: try to use **else** not two condition sentences .

Comment: i tried but in vain. its not working that's why i wrote 2 if statements. Please help me if you have a solution.